# XGetWindowProperty and ctypes

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, x11

#### Question

I'm trying to find `NET_WM_NAME` property for each of the window/client that X11 reports. Problem is that there's nothing returned - number of items is 0 and returned data results in empty string. I've looked at multiple code examples through out github and examples written in C and C++ , specifically [Why is XGetWindowProperty returning null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925377/why-is-xgetwindowproperty-returning-null) as well as [Xlib XGetWindowProperty Zero items returned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31187800/3701431) , however I cannot find where is the problem with my code. Seemingly everything is fine, order of parameters passed to `XGetWindowProperty` function is in accordance with [documentation](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XGetWindowProperty.html), and the function returns success status, but results are empty. Where is the problem with my code ?

#### Code

Below is the code I am working with. The issue is `xgetwindowproperty` function. The other parts below it work fine, and are provided only for completeness.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from ctypes import *

def xgetwindowproperty(display,w):

    actual_type_return   = c_ulong()
    actual_format_return = c_int()
    nitems_return        = c_ulong()
    bytes_after_return   = c_ulong()
    prop_return          = POINTER(c_ubyte)()

    wm_name = Xlib.XInternAtom(display,'_NET_WM_NAME',False)
    utf8atom = Xlib.XInternAtom(display,'UTF8_STRING',False)
    print('_NET_WM_NAME',wm_name, 'UTF8_STRING',utf8atom)

    # AnyPropertyType = c_long(0)
    status = Xlib.XGetWindowProperty(
            display,
            w,
            wm_name,
            0,
            65536, 
            False,
            utf8atom,
            byref(actual_type_return),
            byref(actual_format_return),
            byref(nitems_return),
            byref(bytes_after_return),
            byref(prop_return)
    )
    print(nitems_return.value) # returns 0
    # empty string as result
    print( 'Prop', ''.join([ chr(c) for c in prop_return[:bytes_after_return.value]  ]) ) 

    Xlib.XFree(prop_return)
    print('@'*10)
# -------

Xlib = CDLL("libX11.so.6")
display = Xlib.XOpenDisplay(None)
if display == 0: 
    sys.exit(2)

w = Xlib.XRootWindow(display, c_int(0))

root = c_ulong()
children = POINTER(c_ulong)()
parent = c_ulong()
nchildren = c_uint()

Xlib.XQueryTree(display, w, byref(root), byref(parent), byref(children), byref(nchildren))

for i in range(nchildren.value):
    print("Child:",children[i])
    xgetwindowproperty(display,children[i])
```

Comment: One thing that is certainly wrong is *argtypes* and *restype* not being defined for any of the functions. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53182796/python-ctypes-issue-on-different-oses/53185316#53185316.